# How might I go about solving this definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble solving this integral, I have tried using Mathematica and Sympy but had no luck.

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2 + (\Gamma_0\omega)^2} d\omega $$

If it helps, for the case of interest $\Gamma_0 < \omega_0$ and $\Gamma_0 > 0$ and $\omega_0 > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preliminaries**

Using $a^2+b^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\omega_0^2-\omega^2\right)^2+(\Gamma_0\omega)^2
&=\left(\omega^2+i\Gamma_0\omega-\omega_0^2\right)\left(\omega^2-i\Gamma_0\omega-\omega_0^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
The roots for the two quadratics are
$$
\omega=\frac{\pm i\Gamma_0\pm\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}2
$$
Thus, re-pairing the roots gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(\omega_0^2-\omega^2\right)^2+(\Gamma_0\omega)^2\\
&=\left(\omega^2+\omega\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}+\omega_0^2\right)\left(\omega^2-\omega\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}+\omega_0^2\right)\\
&=\left[\left(\omega+\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2\right]\left[\left(\omega-\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2\right]
\end{align}
$$
Then [Partial Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\left(\omega_0^2-\omega^2\right)^2+(\Gamma_0\omega)^2}\\[12pt]
&=\frac1{2\omega_0^2}\left[\frac{1+\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\left(\omega+\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}
+\frac{1-\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\left(\omega-\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right]
\end{align}
$$

---

**Integration**

Due to the evenness of the integrand,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac1{\left(\omega_0^2-\omega^2\right)^2+(\Gamma_0\omega)^2}\,\mathrm{d}\omega\\[6pt]
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\left(\omega_0^2-\omega^2\right)^2+(\Gamma_0\omega)^2}\,\mathrm{d}\omega\\
&=\frac1{4\omega_0^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[{\small\frac{1+\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\left(\omega+\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}
+\frac{1-\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\left(\omega-\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\right)^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}\omega\\
&=\frac1{4\omega_0^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[{\small\frac{\frac12+\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\omega^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}
+\frac{\frac12-\frac\omega{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2-\Gamma_0^2}}}{\omega^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}\omega\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{4\omega_0^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{\omega^2+\tfrac14\Gamma_0^2}\\[12pt]
&=\frac\pi{2\omega_0^2\Gamma_0}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the full worked example, it turns out I'm quite rusty at pen and paper mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The quartic polynomial can be factored as the product of two quadratic ones. Then the integrand will decompose in simple quadratic fractions with numerators of the first degree. The numerators can be adjusted to be the derivatives of the denominators, and constant numerators will remain. The inverse of a quadratic is turned, by a linear change of variable, to the derivative of $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$, depending on the number of real roots.

Once you have factored the initial polynomial, the rest is quite tractable.

---

After reduction to simple fractions, you can use

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(px%2Bq)%2F(ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc)

(or the definite integral).

---

The roots of the biquadratic equation

$$(a^2-\omega^2)^2+2b^2\omega^2=\omega^4+2(b^2-a^2)\omega^2+a^4=0$$ are

$$\omega=\pm\sqrt{b^2-a^2\pm\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)^2-a^4}}.$$

They can be real or complex. In the case of complex roots, the factorization is

$$(\omega+c+id)(\omega+c-id)(\omega-c+id)(\omega-c-id)=((\omega+c)^2-d^2)((\omega-c)^2-d^2).$$

Comment: I'm trying to factor the quartic polynomial to the product of 2 quadratic polynomials but am having trouble, could you show me how this is done?

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist: just done.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist: I assume so but you changed the notation.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken on the last part.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 11.1 gives me 
$$
\frac{i \pi  \left(\sqrt{-i \Gamma_0 \sqrt{4 {\omega_0}^2-\Gamma_0^2}+\Gamma_0^2-2 {\omega_0}^2}-\sqrt{i \Gamma_0 \sqrt{4 {\omega_0}^2-\Gamma_0^2}+\Gamma_0^2-2 {\omega_0}^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \Gamma_0 \sqrt{i \Gamma_0 \sqrt{4 {\omega_0}^2-\Gamma_0^2}+\Gamma_0^2-2
   {\omega_0}^2} \sqrt{\left(\Gamma_0^2-4 {\omega_0}^2\right) \left(i \Gamma_0 \sqrt{4 {\omega_0}^2-\Gamma_0^2}-\Gamma_0^2+2 {\omega_0}^2\right)}}
$$
but the imaginart part may be spurious comparing to numerical trials if the inputs are real.

Comment: Mathematica 10 gave me the same erroneous answer. The integral is definitely positive real. Plugging in values for $\omega_0$ and $\Gamma_0$ before integrating in Mathematica gives values that match my answer.

Comment: Any idea why Mathematica gives this erroneous answer?

Comment: I think it sometimes assumes things about the complex branches of functions and collects factors of $i\pi$... but i'm not certain.

Comment: This non-answer should rather be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let $a =\omega$ and $b= \Gamma_0$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(a^2-x^2\right)^2+(b x)^2} 
= & 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^4+\left(b^2-2 a^2\right) x^2+a^4} \\
= & 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}+\left(b^2-2 a^2\right)} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{a^2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)-\left(1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)}{x^2+\frac{a^4}{x^2}+\left(b^2-2 a^2\right)} d x \\
= & \frac{1}{a^2}\left[\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{a^2}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{a^2}{x}\right)^2+b^2}-  \underbrace{  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x+\frac{a^2}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{a^2}{x}\right)^2+\left(b^2-4 a^2\right)}}_{=0} \right]\\=& \frac{1}{a^2 b}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\frac{a^2}{x}}{b}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
=&\frac{\pi}{a^2 b}
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence $$\boxed{ \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2 + (\Gamma_0\omega)^2} d\omega = \frac{\pi}{\omega_0^2 \Gamma_0} }$$