# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(a^2 - x^2)^2 + (bx)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to find the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(a^2 - x^2)^2 + (bx)^2}$$

The result is $\pi/a^2b$ but somehow I can't recover that.

I tried the residue theorem but it gave me an awfully long square root of square root residue. Mathematica is giving me also an exact integral with tan$^{-1}$ that I can't get close to the expected result and that is equally complex. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fix your limits of integration.

Comment: If I take $a=1,b=0$ I get $\frac{\pi} 2$ final formula seems erroneous, or maybe it is the integrand. Anyway something off.

Comment: @zwim , the indefinite integral of $1/(x^2-1)^2 $ does not converge right?

Comment: no, because $1$ is a root of the polynomial at the denominator

Comment: Then I don't understand Zwin comment...

Comment: If $a=1$ and $b=0$, you have $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\pi/2$, which is different fromcthe formula you stated

Comment: AAAAH, I MADE A MISTAKE IN THE DENOMINATOR

Comment: Never forget to double-check things with dimensional analysis. It should be $\pi/(a^2b)$ for $a,\,b>0$.

Comment: By the way, there's an easy solution with Glasser's master theorem.

Comment: @J.G. could you roughly sketch the steps? I'm getting a lot of terms from the master theorem that do not seem to make things easier.

Comment: Calling the original even integrand $f(x)$, you can rewrite the integral as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^{-2}f(y^{-1})dy$. That substitution obtains a new integrand that's a function of $y-1/(a^2y)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How might I go about solving this definite integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381256/how-might-i-go-about-solving-this-definite-integral) Next time, before (or instead of asking, please [use Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%20dx%7D%7B(a%5E2%20-%20x%5E2)%5E2%20%2B%20(bx)%5E2%7D%24&p=1) to look for duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(a^2 - x^2)^2 + (bx)^2}$$

= $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(a^4+(-2a^2+b^2)x^2+x^4)}$$

Let $(-2a^2+b^2)$ = $\ p$. Now, dividing and multiplying by $\ 2a^2$, we get:

= $$\frac{1}{2a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(x^2+a^2)-(x^2-a^2)dx}{(a^4+px^2+x^4)}$$

Let $\ I_1$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(x^2+a^2)}{a^4+px^2+x^4}$ and $\ I_2$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(x^2-a^2)}{a^4+px^2+x^4}$

Note that

$$\ I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(x^2+a^2)}{a^4+px^2+x^4}$$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}dx}{x^2 + \frac{a^4}{x^2} + p}$$

Now, let $$\ x - \frac{a^2}{x} = t$$

Then $\ dt$ = $\ 1 + \frac{a^2}{x^2}$ $\cdot$ $\ dx$

Substituting t for x, we get

$$\ I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{dt}{t^2+p+2a^2}$$

Thus,

$$\ I_1 = 2\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{p+2a^2}} = \dfrac{\pi}{b}$$

Proceed in a similar manner for $\ I_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure that $\pi/ab$ is right. I checked numerically with desmos and wolfram accepts to give me a clean answer for a=b=1 which is $\pi$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+1%2F%28%281+-+x%5E2%29%5E2+%2B1x%5E2%29+between+-infinity+and+infinity+

Comment: Maybe I've made some mistake in the calculations. Let me recheck again.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry  I made a mistake in the denominator. It is a minus and not a plus

Comment: Okay. The procedure remains the same. Let me do the modifications. Please let me know if my answer is correct by upvoting.

Comment: It gives the wanted result. THANKS

Comment: Before (or instead of) answering, please [use Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%20dx%7D%7B(a%5E2%20-%20x%5E2)%5E2%20%2B%20(bx)%5E2%7D%24&p=1) to look for duplicates. To keep this site tidy, your answer would be better located [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381256) than here.

Answer (score 2):

$(a^2+x^2)^2 + (bx)^2 = 0\\
a^2+ x^2 = \pm ibx\\
x^2 \pm ibx + a^2 = 0\\
x = \frac {\pm ib \pm i\sqrt {b^2 + 4a^2}}{2}$

We have 2 roots in the upper half-plane.

The residues appear to be

$2\pi i \left(\frac {1}{(ib)(ib + i\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})(i\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})}+ \frac {1}{(-ib)(-ib + i\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})(i\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})}\right)$

We factor out $i^3$ from the denominators.  Both fractions have similar terms in the denominator.  The common denominator is

$(b)(\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})(b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})(-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}) = 4a^2b\sqrt{b^2+4a^2})$

$\frac {2\pi i}{i^3}(\frac {-b +\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}}{4a^2b\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}} - \frac {b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}}{4a^2b\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}})$

$\pi(\frac {1}{a^2\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}})$

And the contour along the semi-circle goes to 0 as the radius goes to infinity.  Which is obvious do to the degree of the x terms in the denominator.

Comment: Before (or instead of) answering, please [use Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%20dx%7D%7B(a%5E2%20-%20x%5E2)%5E2%20%2B%20(bx)%5E2%7D%24&p=1) to look for duplicates. To keep this site tidy, your answer would be better located [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381256) than here.

Comment: Anyway, [the question was modified](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4822969/4) 10 min before this answer, which became then off topic.